# For ajax post, where should data to be passed be located?

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I am using a homegrown MVC framework.  The client passes the current page #, the controller name, the desired task, and any pertinent data to the server.  All of this information can either be in the URL or in the post object.

I would strongly suspect that the data to be saved should be stored in the post object, and probably the task as well since it applies only to post data.  The page number and controller name maybe makes sense more in the URL since I will have similar get requests with the same page number and controller.  I show it this way in the example below.

Where should I locate the information to be passed, and why?  Thank you

```
$.post('index.php?page=123&controller=edit',{task:'saveSomething', data:'whatever'});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "locate the information to be passed?"

Comment: What you have there will pass the TASK and DATA variables as POST objects to index.php. PAGE and CONTROLLER will be passed in the GET/URL object depending on language. What is your question? You could move PAGE and CONTROLLER after DATA and have everything in the POST object.

Comment: @ExplosionPills.  The page number, the controller name, the task, and any data to be sent to the server.

Comment: @Leeish.  My question is whether I should move page number and controller name into the post object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **GET** if you are retrieving an existing resource on a server, and **POST** if you creating a resource or modifying an existing one. You should read up on the HTTP specs.

That being said, it is probably easiest to put all of your data in a **POST** object.

ex.

```
var post_data = {
  page:123,
  controller:'edit',
  //other data
};

$.post('/url',post_data,function(response){/*callback function*/});
```

Going even further, you should have a *page controller*, with an *edit action* that the page id gets passed to. Then you would have the controller and action you want to reach in the url section, and the id of the resource in the POST data.

Depending on the scope of your application, you should most likely be using a framework that would handle this type of thing for you. This way your application will maintain a consistent structure and 99% of these roadblocks have already been thought through by other users. You may want to look into using something like CodeIgniter, CakePHP, FuelPHP, etc...

Comment: You indicated that I should have "the controller and action you want to reach in the url section, and the id of the resource in the POST data."  I guess that is what I was originally thinking, but it sounds like you also indicated that I should put everything in the POST data.  Which way do you recommend?

Comment: The way you currently have your application designed, you might as well put it in the POST data. But for future reference, it is not the *proper* way to do it. Look into using an MVC pattern/framework.

Comment: Thanks Ethan,  Please point me in the direction of what I am not doing properly.

Comment: Well said. I would personally prefer a url like `/c/page-id/controller-id` (REST) and post all other data. On the server, use url-rewrite for `/c/*`

Comment: For objects in a database, such as in this case 'pages', you should have a controller which interacts with your model and view, then you would have within that controller an 'edit' action that performs the operation on the given page_id.

Comment: Thanks Ethan,  I wasn't clear with the "page" part.  It really represented a component or given part of the application.  Each component could have one or more controllers, and the controllers have tasks like edit associated with them.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would better if you use only one approach, either GET (the url) or POST.

And to me, POST is always a better way. Unless you specifically want to use the URL to pass the data.

Comment: That being said, in order to permalink, you'll need them in the URL. The Rails/Wheels approach I believe uses  `domain.com/controller/action/key` type route be default if I remember correctly. Any additional params get passed in after the key as `?param=value`

Comment: The page number and the controller in a sense defines the page.  The task might be GetSomeStuff in which GET should be used, or SaveSomeStuff in which POST should be used.  That's why I was thinking the page number and controller should always be in the URL regardless of whether GET or POST is used.  Maybe just my silly idea...

Answer (score 0):

Your query is right.

I assume that you want `page` and `controller` parameters to be made available at $_GET and `task` and `data` as $_POST. However, the problem seems to be for the `Content-Type` header, which you cannot control via this method.

See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/ajax.js#L143
The magic lies at https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/1.4.2/src/ajax.js#L205

- Option 1:
  Set the headers:
  `$.ajaxSettings['headers'] = [ 'Content-Type': 'application/form-www-url-encoded']`.
  Do this only once.
- Option 2:
  Use `$.ajax`

> ```
> $.ajax({
>     type: "POST",
>     headers: ['Content-Type': 'application/form-www-url-encoded'],
>     url: 'index.php?page=123&controller=edit',
>     data: {task:'saveSomething', data:'whatever'},
> });
> ```